# For any real number r, show that the list of functions is a set of linearly independent functions

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

For any real number $r$, show that the list of functions is a set of linearly independent functions:
$$e^{rt}, te^{rt}, t^2e^{rt},\dots,t^ne^{rt}.$$
I know that to show, I'd have to start out with a polynomial 
$$y(t)=c_0+c_1t+c_2t^2+\dots+c_nt^n=0$$
Or something like that, but don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Well, you might use the Wronskian. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Assume that such list of functions is a set of linearly dependent functions. Then there are real numbers $c_0,\dots, c_n$, not all zero, such that the identity
$$c_0e^{rt}+c_1te^{rt}+c_2t^2e^{rt}+\dots+c_nt^ne^{rt}=0$$
holds for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. After dividing by $e^{rt}$ (which is positive), this is equivalent to
$$c_0+c_1t+c_2t^2+\dots+c_nt^n=0.$$
What is the limit of the left-hand side as $t\to +\infty$?

Consider the largest index $i$ such that  $c_i\not=0$ and see if you get a contradiction.

Comment: And for the function to be linearly dependent the terms must equal the function of 0? So like $c_0=y(0)=0$

Comment: Alternatively, the polynomial can only be $0$ for finitely many $t$ by the theorem that a non-zero polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots over any field.

Comment: @LexyFidds if $i>0$ then the limit is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$;  if $i=0$ then the limit is $c_0\not=0$. In any case you get a contradiction because the r.h.s is zero.